# PUT request to Acumatica Sales Order endpoint doesn't create record

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a sales order in Acumatica via default contract-based rest api, but instead of creating a record I seem to only be able to fetch records. I'm happy to provide more info, but curious if anyone can point out what's wrong with this request. I tried following the docs and other online resources but haven't been able to figure it out yet. Many thanks, James

Here is request in postman:
[Sales Order Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpTwU.png)

And here is the create SO form in Acumatica:
[Create SO form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Rrq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out! In postman, under settings, make sure that the "follow original http method" option is checked. I haven't run into this before, but if that isn't checked the http method will be converted to "GET", which explains why I was only able to retrieve records

[Postman settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXuZ7.png)